# Converting a swift 4 string to c unsigned char *

Tags: ios, c, swift

I'm trying to interact with a C API from Swift and was able to successfully convert unsigned char* to String but am not able to convert back a String to unsigned char *

Here is my C function that returns the passed string:

```
unsigned char* test(unsigned char* hello) {
    return hello;
}
```

Here is my swift code to call the c function which doesn't work:

> let str = "hello, world!"
> print(String(cString:test(str)))

Its goal is to pass "hello, world" to c and then have c pass "hello, world" back and then print it.

I've tried the solutions from here but they all seem outdated for Swift 4

Buffer attempt:

> let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.allocate(capacity: 4)
>
> _ = buffer.initialize(from: 1...4)
>
> print(String(cString: test(buffer)))

Error:

Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer!'

Comment: "I''ve tried the solutions from here" like what?

Comment: Returning the pointer that you get from an automatic `String`-to-pointer conversion is unsafe because its storage is only guaranteed to be valid for the duration of the call. If your C API actually does something like that, you won't be able to use automatic conversions.

Comment: What is `String`?

Comment: @WeatherVane, it is the standard string type in Swift.

Comment: How do you recommend me to do this if I wanted a string "hello world to go to c and then back?

Comment: You need to use [UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.allocate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablebufferpointer/2949512-allocate), copy your string in there, do whatever you need to do, and then deallocate the buffer pointer.

Comment: This is the place where you should be using `char`, without an `unsigned` qualifier. You are actually dealing with characters, not integrals between `UCHAR_MIN` and `UCHAR_MAX`

Comment: I'm really close now. I created a buffer and am trying to pass it to the test(unsigned char*) function but it's giving me an error. http://prntscr.com/kgt27z Do you have any idea how to convert UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!

Comment: Update your question and show all code you tried.

Comment: I've updated the question with my buffer attempt. The C code is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to specify the Element type for `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`.
- The pointer to the content of `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` can be accessed through the property `baseAddress`.

Try this:

```
let str = "hello, world!"

let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: str.utf8.count + 1)
defer {buffer.deallocate()}

memcpy(buffer.baseAddress, str, str.utf8.count + 1)

print(String(cString: test(buffer.baseAddress)))
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!